# Why do I need numeric constant?

Tags: rpgle

I'm extremely new to RPGLE and I'm getting some errors like:

`The length parameter must be a numeric constant between 1 and the maximum for the type. (20).`

on all of my zoned variables. And I'm getting

`The Factor 2 operand is not valid for the specified operation. (30).`

On my `Write ClassAverage;` What is factor 2 operand?

```
**FREE

dcl-f wuexampl1 Disk Usage(*Input) ;
dcl-f ch6print printer Usage(*output);

dcl-s Totalscore zoned(3,0);
dcl-s FIN char(1);
dcl-s RecordCount zoned(2,0);
dcl-s AverageScore zoned(3,0);
dcl-s ClassAverage zoned(3,0);



Write HEADER;
Read EXAMREC;
DOW Not %eof(wuexampl1);
    AverageScore = (Exam1 + Exam2 + Exam3 + Exam4 + Exam5) / 5;
    Totalscore += AverageScore;
    FIN = SFNAME;
    RecordCount += 1;
    Write DETAIL;
    Read EXAMREC;
enddo;
    ClassAverage = Totalscore / RecordCount;
    Write ClassAverage;

*inlr = *on;
return;
```

Answer (score 2):

> The length parameter must be a numeric constant between 1 and the
> maximum for the type. (20).

RPG uses `:` not `,` as parameter separators, try

```
dcl-s RecordCount zoned(2:0);
dcl-s AverageScore zoned(3:0);
dcl-s ClassAverage zoned(3:0);
```

> The Factor 2 operand is not valid for the specified operation. (30).

In RPG, you write Record Formats (if multiple formats in a file, ie. Printer files) or Files (if a single format DB file), not individual fields.

Instead of

```
Write ClassAverage;
```

You need to write the appropriate record in the `ch6print` file.  You're successfully writing `HEADER`, `DETAIL`, there's probably a `TOTALS` or `AVERAGE` record.

Comment: `     A            CLASSAVG       3S 0   6 72`

Is this the record you mean? when I change   Write ClassAverage; to the following... I'm still getting the same operand error.
`  CLASSAVG = Totalscore / RecordCount;
    Write CLASSAVG;`

Comment: That's still an individual field in the printer file, you need the record name that field is in.  Record name should have a `R` in column 17.